# Check if an array is a subsequence of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, subsequence

Given this arrays I want to check if "sequence" is a subsequence of "array", meaning all the numbers exist in the original array and in the same order:

```
array = [5, 1, 22, 25, 6, -1, 8, 10];
sequence = [1, 6, -1, 10];
```

Not sure why my code doesn't work.

```
function isValidSubsequence(array, sequence) {
    let seqIdx = 0;
    let arrId = 0;
    for (const value of sequence ){
        if (seqIdx === sequence.length) break;
        if (array[arrId] === value) {
            seqIdx++;
            arrId++;
        }
    }

    return seqIdx === sequence.length
}
```

Comment: Subset... or substring?

Comment: This should work

  `const result = sequence.every(el => array.includes(el));`

Comment: @HariHaravelan that won't account for order

Comment: @Phil Yes right, my bad

Comment: Thanks! it worked and makes sense

Answer (score 2):

Your solution doesn't work because it never moves past the first entry in `array`. You never increment any of your indexes unless the `sequence` value matches `array[arrId]`.

I'd use [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) with the second `fromIndex` parameter to create a shrinking window of `array` as you search. If you ever reach an iteration of `sequence` that cannot be found, you know it fails the test

```js
function isValidSubsequence(array, sequence) {
  let index = -1;
  for (const value of sequence) {
    index = array.indexOf(value, index + 1); // find the next sequence value
    if (index === -1) {
      return false; // not found, return false immediately
    }
  }
  return true;
}

const array = [5, 1, 22, 25, 6, -1, 8, 10];
const sequence = [1, 6, -1, 10];

console.log("valid sub-sequence:", isValidSubsequence(array, sequence));
console.log("out of order:", isValidSubsequence(array, [25, 22]));
console.log("unknown elements:", isValidSubsequence(array, [5, 11]));
```

Comment: @SebastianSimon nice one, I hadn't accounted for repeated elements in the sequence correctly.

Answer (score 1):

**Remove `arrIdx`.**

In a `for...of` loop the index of `array` isn't needed in this case since `value` progresses on each iteration.

**Remove the first flow control statement.**

```
if (seqIdx === sequence.length) break;
```

There's no need to interupt the loop. The Boolean returned outside of the loop is sufficient.

**Change the second flow control statement to monitor `sequence[seqIdx]` not `array`**

```
if (sequence[seqIdx] === value) {
  seqIdx++;
}
```

The key to this algorithm is to progress through `array` one number at a time (as is the norm), but not the `sequence`. The counter, `seqIdx`, only progresses on a match so basically if `sequence` ends before or at the end of the loop it is a valid subsequence.

```js
const arr = [5, 1, 22, 25, 6, -1, 8, 10];
const seq = [1, 6, -1, 10];

function isValidSubsequence(array, sequence) {
  let seqIdx = 0;
  for (const value of array) {
    if (sequence[seqIdx] === value) {
      seqIdx++;
    }
  }
  return seqIdx === sequence.length;
};
console.log(isValidSubsequence(arr, seq));
```

Comment: `for (const value of sequence)` <--- I wonder if there's any chance this needs to be `for (const value of array)`? Or, may be I'm missing something here.

Comment: OOpps!  Updated thanks.

Comment: Thanks! it worked and makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in a simple way by finding the index of sequence array elements from the original array and then check if the indexed array is sorted or not.

**Demo :**

```js
const array = [5, 1, 22, 25, 6, -1, 8, 10];
const sequence = [1, 6, -1, 10];

// Find index of the elements from the original array.
const indexArr = sequence.map((item) => array.indexOf(item));

// Now test if this indexed array is sorted or not to check if sequence array having same order as per the original array.
function isSorted(arr) {
  var i = 0;
  var last = arr.length - 1;
  return (function check() {
    return (i >= last) || (arr[i] <= arr[++i] && check());
  })();
}

console.log(isSorted(indexArr))
```